# Stripping text from one point to another in python

Tags: python

I have a file textfile.txt:

```
[X:Y:Z]
```

How would I strip "X:" and ":Z" so that I am left with "Y"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.strip) and [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split):

```
>>> '[X:Y:Z]'.strip('[]')
'X:Y:Z'
>>> '[X:Y:Z]'.strip('[]').split(':')
['X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> '[X:Y:Z]'.strip('[]').split(':')[1]
'Y'
```

**UPDATE**

As Blender commented, stripping the brackets off is not necessary.

```
>>> '[X:Y:Z]'.split(':')
['[X', 'Y', 'Z]']
>>> '[X:Y:Z]'.split(':')[1]
'Y'
```

Comment: I don't really see why you need to strip the brackets off: `'[X:Y:Z]'.split(':')[1]`

Answer (score 1):

`Y = "[X:Y:Z]".split(':')[1]`

That's a quick one liner for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of ways you could achieve this for the single example you've posted, e.g.:

```
full_string = '[X:Y:Z]'
first, middle, last = full_string.split(':')
print(middle)
Out[5]: 'Y'
```

To narrow down what will or won't work, you may have to post some more examples that make clearer how your data format looks, and what pieces of information you need to extract from it.